# Using vfprintf without a wrapper function?

Tags: c, stderr, stdio, printf

I want to replace the fprintf call in `fprintf(stderr, "Error occured with file %s\n", file);` with `vfprintf(FILE * stream, const char * format, va_list arg)` because of the bloat that fprintf inherits.
Is it possible to use vfprintf without having to write a wrapper function for this, e.g. creating the va_list argument somehow?

Comment: `fprintf` is by itself a very thin wrapper of `vfprintf` so 
"the bloat that fprintf inherits" is actually vfprintf one. Otherwise you need to explain what exactly you think is the bloat.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. I'm linking my code against dietlibc, which warns me when compiling that printf is bloat: `/opt/diet/lib-x86_64/libc.a(vfprintf.o): In function \`vfprintf': (.text+0x2e): warning: warning: the printf functions add several kilobytes of bloat.` What solution is there to get less bloat and no warning?

Comment: The "bloat" being referred to is from the entire printf family, including `vfprintf`. The only way to avoid it is to not use string formatting functions at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above, it sounds like you actually want to avoid the `printf` family of functions completely.

In that case, you could use something along these lines:

```
fputs("Error occured with file ", stderr);
fputs(file, stderr);
fputc('\n', stderr);
```